# How can we Install .ipkg (installer binary for IGel OS) file in ubuntu/Igel OS(perfered version 12)?

Tags: package-management

In IGel OS 12 (thin client based on Ubuntu), we have the installer files as .ipkg file? How can we install it through command line. Any package manager for Igel OS(yum and apt-get doesn't work here)? OR Is there any other way to install the app(.ipkg) file in ubuntu machine.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.

Comment: Ubuntu's packages are either *deb* (where `apt` or `apt-get` will work), OR if using a Core product then as *snap* packages only are used you use the `snap` command.  No on-topic product uses *ipkg* packages (by default).

Answer (score 0):

```
igelpkgctl install -f ./file.ipkg
igelpkgctl list available
igelpkgctl install <something from the list above>
```